# Firebase Anonymous Auth, Nil User

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase database and offer anonymous login. The first anonymous login made on a single device works as expected. If I sign out and attempt any more anonymous logins, it succeeds, the completion block has no error and returns a user.

However, once it's all done and we're out of the completion block, `Auth.auth().currentUser()` is nil.

If I run a simple `Timer` checking `Auth.auth().currentUser()` every second, throughout the entire login process it is always nil and never changes.

Quick breakdown of code:

1. Login anonymously.
2. Check if id exists in db.
3. Update profile `displayName` with id for easy referral later.
4. Fetch client in db.
5. All go wrong!

Tap a button to sign in.

```
@IBAction func clientLoginBtnTap(_ sender : UIButton) {
        self.clientActivityIndicator?.showActivityIndicator()
        
        Auth.auth().signInAnonymously { (user, error) in
            if error == nil {
                //check id matches available client
                self.checkClient(id: (self.clientIdField?.text)!, completion: { (isValid) in
                    if isValid == true {
                        //now signed in, update client id
                        let profileChangeRequest = user?.createProfileChangeRequest()
                        profileChangeRequest?.displayName = self.clientIdField?.text
                        profileChangeRequest?.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in
                            if error == nil {
                                //done
                                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: kIS_USER_CLIENT_NOT_TRAINER)
                                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                                    //self.delegate?.didLoginAsClient()
                                })
                            }
                            else {
                                self.logout()
                                self.clientIdField?.shake()
                                self.clientActivityIndicator?.hideActivityIndicator()
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    else {
                        self.logout()
                        self.clientIdField?.shake()
                        self.clientActivityIndicator?.hideActivityIndicator()
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                
            }
        }
    }

func checkClient(id : String, completion: @escaping (_ isValid : Bool) -> Void) {
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("v2").child("clients").child(id)
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() { completion(true) }
            else { completion(false) }
        }) { (error) in
            completion(false)
        }
    }

func logout() {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print (error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Login is successful.

Then this runs after login and the `user` exists but `Auth.auth().currentUser()` is nil. When a client login happens, I try to get the client data but permission is denied because we have no user.

```
handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
            self.currentUser = user
            
            if user == nil {
                self.updateForNoUser()
            }
            else {
                self.updateForUser()
            }
        }

func updateForUser() {
        //Trainer Logged in
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: kIS_USER_CLIENT_NOT_TRAINER) == false {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "master", sender: self)
        }
        //Client Logged in
        else {
            if let id = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName {
                let ref = Database.database().reference().child("v2").child("clients").child(id)
                ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    if snapshot.exists() {
                        self.client = Client(snapshot: snapshot)
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "masterClient", sender: self)
                    }
                }) { (error) in }
            }
            else {
                do {
                    try Auth.auth().signOut()
                }
                catch let error as NSError {
                    print (error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the entire code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: None of the code you shared *uses* `self.currentUser` so it's hard to say where the mistake is.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sorry I was trying to keep it simple. I have now included all of the offending code.

Comment: Keeping it simple is a great idea for getting help. But the recommended way for that is to recreate the problem in isolation, instead of copying bits from your current project. See [how to a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more help on getting help.

Comment: I'm not sure why `Auth.auth().currentUser` would be unassigned when you check. But consider passing the current user from the auth state listener into `updateForUser` with: `self.updateForUser(user)`.